# How to get sendgrid batch email request callback when all mail processed.

Tags: batch-processing, sendgrid, email, jira-rest-api

I am using Sendgrid to send email to our users

To fulfill our requirement i am making a batch request by adding a category Id.

I just want to call a functionality(update my email source).when sendgrid processed every email from requested batch.

Is their any way to set a callback in a email request that sendgrid call a link when all the mail of a batch is processed.